# Forced directed D3 Graph setting specific image for each node

Tags: d3.js

Hi I have gone through few questions and possible solutions of putting image as node in forced directed. But all of them are either putting randomly or one image for all. Is there any way i can assign particular image to particular node? Basically i am creating dynamically and fetching data from database. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try as shown in fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/n28k7oqo/3/

You can specify your data as and pass the image as shown below

```
var graph = {
  "nodes": [
    {"x": 469, "y": 410, 'img': "https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/industry-2/96/Mine-512.png"},
    {"x": 493, "y": 364, 'img': "https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ikooni-outline-free-basic/128/free-09-128.png"},
    {"x": 442, "y": 365, 'img': "https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ikooni-outline-free-basic/128/free-17-128.png"},
    {"x": 467, "y": 314, 'img': "https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ikooni-outline-free-basic/128/free-22-128.png"},
    {"x": 477, "y": 248, 'img': "https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ikooni-outline-free-basic/128/free-13-128.png"},
    {"x": 425, "y": 207, 'img': "https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/industry-2/96/Mine-512.png"},
    {"x": 402, "y": 155, 'img': "https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ikooni-outline-free-basic/128/free-03-128.png"},
    {"x": 369, "y": 196, 'img': "https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/industry-2/96/Mine-512.png"},
    {"x": 350, "y": 148, 'img': "https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/industry-2/96/Mine-512.png"},
    {"x": 539, "y": 222, 'img': "https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/industry-2/96/Mine-512.png"},
    {"x": 594, "y": 235, 'img': "https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ikooni-outline-free-basic/128/free-23-128.png"},
    {"x": 582, "y": 185, 'img': "https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/industry-2/96/Mine-512.png"},
    {"x": 633, "y": 200, 'img': "https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/industry-2/96/Mine-512.png"}
  ],
  "links": [
    {"source":  0, "target":  1},
    {"source":  1, "target":  2},
    {"source":  2, "target":  0},
    {"source":  1, "target":  3},
    {"source":  3, "target":  2},
    {"source":  3, "target":  4},
    {"source":  4, "target":  5},
    {"source":  5, "target":  6},
    {"source":  5, "target":  7},
    {"source":  6, "target":  7},
    {"source":  6, "target":  8},
    {"source":  7, "target":  8},
    {"source":  9, "target":  4},
    {"source":  9, "target": 11},
    {"source":  9, "target": 10},
    {"source": 10, "target": 11},
    {"source": 11, "target": 12},
    {"source": 12, "target": 10}
  ]
}
```

### Explanation

The x and y in the json is the probable place where you want to place the circle. Imagine you don't have x and y for any of the nodes; in such case don't pass the x and y in JSON. Something like this:

```
 ..."nodes": [
{ 

'img': "https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/industry-2/96/Mine-512.png"
}, ....
```

Regarding the img pass the url of the image you wish to see on the node.
Like I have done above.

This will append the image to the node group:

```
  //make groups which will hold the image and the circle
  nodes = node.data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("g");

  //make a node circle in the group                   
  var circles = nodes.append("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("r", 12)
      .on("dblclick", dblclick)
      .call(drag);
  //make images in the group
var images = nodes.append("svg:image")
    .attr("xlink:href",function(d) {return d.img})
    .attr("height", "20")
    .attr("width", "20");
```

The node group is the group which contains the circle and the image.

Comment: Thank you very much i wish i could have marked two answers as correct :)

Comment: Can you please explain little bit about image append to the node. I can see X & Y in your nodes section. Actually i am still facing issue while integrating image part in my javascript code.

Comment: @Ethen applogies for my late reply. I have added some explanation you are seeking, in my answers **Edit** section. Please check and let me know if you still have any doubts...

Answer (score 2):

hi just click the load button and heres the sample of what you want http://jsfiddle.net/elviz/V6Qr8/91/

```
function loadImage() {
    if (LoadData) {
        root = {
            "name": "physics",
                "imageURL": "",
                "type": "user",
                "children": [{
                "name": "DragForce",
                    "imageURL": "",
                    "size": 1082,
                    "type": "user"
            }, {
                "name": "GravityForce",
                    "imageURL": "",
                    "size": 1336,
                    "type": "user"
            }, {
                "name": "IForce",
                    "imageURL": "",
                    "size": 319,
                    "type": "user"
            }, {
                "name": "NBodyForce",
                    "imageURL": "",
                    "size": 10498,
                    "type": "user"
            }, {
                "name": "Node 1",
                    "imageURL": "",
                    "type": "user",
                    "children": [{
                    "name": "DragForce 1.1",
                        "imageURL": "",
                        "size": 1082,
                        "type": "chat"
                }, {
                    "name": "DragForce 1.2",
                        "imageURL": "",
                        "size": 1082,
                        "type": "message"
                }]
            },

            {
                "name": "Particle",
                    "imageURL": "",
                    "size": 2822,
                    "type": "user"
            }, {
                "name": "Simulation",
                    "imageURL": "",
                    "size": 9983,
                    "type": "user"
            }, {
                "name": "Node 2",
                    "imageURL": "",
                    "type": "user",
                    "children": [{
                    "name": "DragForce 2.1",
                        "imageURL": "",
                        "size": 1082,
                        "type": "message"
                }, {
                    "name": "DragForce 2.2",
                        "imageURL": "",
                        "size": 1082,
                        "type": "message"
                }]
            },

            {
                "name": "Spring",
                    "imageURL": "",
                    "size": 2213,
                    "type": "user"
            }, {
                "name": "SpringForce",
                    "imageURL": "",
                    "size": 1681,
                    "type": "user"
            }, {
                "name": "Node 3",
                    "imageURL": "",
                    "type": "user",
                    "children": [{
                    "name": "DragForce 2.1",
                        "imageURL": "",
                        "size": 1082,
                        "type": "chat"
                }, {
                    "name": "DragForce 3.2",
                        "imageURL": "",
                        "size": 1082,
                        "type": "chat"
                }]
            }]
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Like in my [**Arda family tree**](http://arda-maps.org/familytree/) I load the images locally by the name of the person. So every person has it's own picture.

Also make sure that you have the onerror in HTML used to show a default image when the wanted image is deleted or something else. Otherwhise the Google Chrome shows an **ugly red cross**. Just as a tip =)

If you have any further question, just ask.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much kwoxer.. I took the idea of chrome red mark!! :)